# How to INSERT INTO using html checked boxes with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, checkbox

**What I need**


I have the results of an Oracle query being displayed on a webpage in an html table. I have also added another column for checkboxes in each row. My code for this is below.

```
<?php

(...some code with Oracle Query...)

echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<table>";

while($row = oci_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SKU'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LOCATION_MAX'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['QUANTITY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

(...some more code...)

?>
```

When the checkbox for each row is clicked, I need to use INSERT INTO for a MySQL table that I have in another database.

I am having trouble wrapping my brain around how I am supposed to grab all of the information for each row and pass it to another script so I can insert the data into the MySQL table.


**What I have tried**


I figured that I would store each value of the row in an array, and then put that into the checkboxes `value` attribute and reference it with the `name` attribute, like so:

```
...
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
while($row = oci_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $rowVal = array(
        "SKU" => $row['SKU'],
        "DESCRIPTION" => $row['DESCRIPTION'],
        "LOCATION_MAX" => $row['LOCATION_MAX'],
        "QUANTITY" => $row['QUANTITY']
    );

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SKU'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LOCATION_MAX'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['QUANTITY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='" . $rowVal . "'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

So, I am trying to reference this in the `$_POST['name']` attribute in the bottom of the script (or in another script). See below.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkVal) {
        /*(do stuff here, like print out all check rows first
        so I can understand what is going on, then eventually
        write the MySQL INSERT INTO query.)*/
}
```

**What My Problems Are**


1) Quite honestly, I am having trouble wrapping my brain around this in the first place. I really thought that storing all of the `$row` information in an array and assigning that array variable to the `value` attribute would work no problem. However, I can't figure out how to call all checked boxes once the submit button is pressed.

The thing is, when I put the array in the `value` attribute, I get an error/notice that reads `Notice: Array to string conversion in [/script location.php] on line [where the checkbox code is]`.

2) Let's say I didn't care about the notice above. I still need to reference the data that is checked so I can insert it into the MySQL database I have. I don't even see this as being difficult. Once I reference all of the checked data, I can cycle through that array with a foreach and execute an insert query for each row in the query.

How do I make this happen? Thanks in advance! If I left out any vital information that any helper needs, please let me know and I can update this question.

My only request is that any solutions offered be in the scope of PHP, HTML, and CSS/Oracle/MySQL if needed. I am not too familiar with Javascript or any of it's libraries and because this is somewhat time-sensitive, I don't have the time to learn all that might go into it. So unless there is a javascript answer that is super straight forward, it will do more harm than good in my case.

Thanks!

-Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty and without testing but...

```
$rowNum = 0;
while($row = oci_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $rowVal = array(
       "SKU" => $row['SKU'],
       "DESCRIPTION" => $row['DESCRIPTION'],
       "LOCATION_MAX" => $row['LOCATION_MAX'],
        "QUANTITY" => $row['QUANTITY']
    )

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SKU'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LOCATION_MAX'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['QUANTITY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .
           "<input type='hidden' name='opt[$rowNum]' value='". implode("::", $rowVal) ."'>".
           "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[$rowNum]' value='$rowNum'>".
         "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $rowNum++;
}
```

You just put the array value in a hidden input and then on your post handling code:

```
// Note that you need to check if all values are $_POSTEd, 
// this is a quick and dirty solution!
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $data = [];
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $rowNum) {
    $data[] = explode("::", $_POST['opt'][$rowNum]);
  }
  var_dump($data);
}

// Output sample (selected row 2 and 4):
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'SKU2' (length=4)
      1 => string 'DESC2' (length=5)
      2 => string 'LOC2' (length=4)
      3 => string 'QUAN2' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'SKU4' (length=4)
      1 => string 'DESC4' (length=5)
      2 => string 'LOC4' (length=4)
      3 => string 'QUAN4' (length=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Can you please elaborate on how to "check" which checkbox was checked?

Comment: This is what happens when I implement the code above.
`Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in /xxxx/xxxx.php on line 755
Notice: Undefined index: opt in /xxxx/xxxx.php on line 755`

Comment: Wow, I realised that we are talking about check boxes, not radio buttons (my bad!), so my solution does not apply directly because  you can select more than one row, so you need to turn the checkbox into an array also (see edited answer)

Comment: Thanks. Before you updated your answer, I used part of your original solution by imploding the array and assigning as the value of the checkbox (didn't see the need to add a hidden input), and then wound up referencing which checkbox was marked with an `if(isset...)` statement, a `foreach` loop, and an `explode` function, almost exactly the same way you did in your edited answer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @mTorres could you tell how write the data into mysql table the var_dump($data); ?